Oracle parameterized query for explain plan in C#
I have an explain plan query and I need to call with parameters in my .Net application. When I try it as following it gives me ORA-1780 Error. I have many parameterized queries in my application but this script is not working. How could I fix it?
private static readonly string sql =@"EXPLAIN PLAN SET STATEMENT_ID = :statementId FOR :sqlScript";

  using (OracleCommand cmd1 = new OracleCommand(PrepareCostOracleSqlPattern, con))
  {
                        cmd1.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("statementId", statementId));
                        cmd1.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("sqlScript", sqlScript));
                        cmd1.CommandTimeout = 6000;
                        object result = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }


ORA-01780: string literal required


As an aside, what is the business reason for generating explain plans as part of your C# application? This appears to be something you would do as a DBA activity and could run directly on the database rather than trying to write code to do it dynamically in the application.

EXPLAIN PLAN does not work with parameterised queries; instead you need to build the query using string concatenation:
Something like (untested, but you should get the general idea):
private static readonly string sql =@"EXPLAIN PLAN SET STATEMENT_ID = '{0}' FOR {1}";

using (OracleCommand cmd1 = new OracleCommand(String.Format(sql, statementId, sqlScript), con))
{
  cmd1.CommandTimeout = 6000;
  object result = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

You can replicate the problem (and the solution) in SQL using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to try using combinations of bind variables and string concatenation:
DECLARE
  v_sql VARCHAR2(4000) := 'SELECT * FROM DUAL';
  v_id  PLS_INTEGER    := 42;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'EXPLAIN PLAN SET STATEMENT_ID = :1 FOR :2'
    USING v_id, v_sql;
END;
/

Fails with:
ORA-01780: string literal required
ORA-06512: at line 5

Concatenating the SQL statement:
DECLARE
  v_sql VARCHAR2(4000) := 'SELECT * FROM DUAL';
  v_id  PLS_INTEGER    := 42;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'EXPLAIN PLAN SET STATEMENT_ID = :1 FOR ' || v_sql
    USING v_id;
END;
/

Also fails as a literal is expected for the statement id:
ORA-01780: string literal required
ORA-06512: at line 5

Using a literal for the statement id:
DECLARE
  v_sql VARCHAR2(4000) := 'SELECT * FROM DUAL';
  v_id  PLS_INTEGER    := 42;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'EXPLAIN PLAN SET STATEMENT_ID = ''' || v_id || ''' FOR :1'
    USING v_sql;
END;
/

Also fails as the SQL statement needs to be concatenated as well:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
ORA-06512: at line 5

Concatenating both:
DECLARE
  v_sql VARCHAR2(4000) := 'SELECT * FROM DUAL';
  v_id  PLS_INTEGER    := 42;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'EXPLAIN PLAN SET STATEMENT_ID = ''' || v_id || ''' FOR ' || v_sql;
END;
/

1 rows affected

Works.
fiddle

Hi, I already builded my query using string concatenation but it causes Sql Injection Error

@alinz I assume that you are using an external tool to check for SQL injection issues (as I don't remember C# providing that out-of-the-box); if so then you should be able to disable the check in specific cases (which would apply to this case).

@alinz I think you need to run the scan and it will bring this up as an issue and you can suppress the issue by marking it as "not an issue" and then, when you want to scan again, import the previous false positives before scanning so that they are ignored.

Ok, I will suppress the issue thank you so much

You appear to be using bind variables in an EXPLAIN PLAN statement. Oracle doesn't permit the use bind variables in the parameters of an EXPLAIN PLAN statement, similar to how you can't use binds in DDL. Binds are only for SQL (selects and DML) and PL/SQL.
So, instead of using : and adding parameters, use C# conventions to simply employ string concatenation to splice in the statement id and SQL statement. You wouldn't want to do this with executable SQL, but it's fine for something exceptional like an explain plan or an occasional DDL.
